# VS2015 Method Auto-complete has no brackets

Tags: visual-studio

if I type this in **eclipse**,and push "Alt+/"  and "enter"

```
new Strin
```

it will show follow by its Auto-complete function

```
new String()
```

but,when I type the same on **VS**,it will show

```
new String
```

there is no "()"in the end,why is it so?Can I change it on settings?

Comment: please check this [URL]()it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Visual Studio Addin like **Resharper** which provides this feature. Download is available at this [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EA4AC039-1B5C-4D11-804E-9BEDE2E63ECF)

Also, for auto completion for constructor, you can press <kbd>ctr</kbd> and  <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

For autocompletion of Braces, you can configure settings in Visual Studio. 
[image]